# How to write a custom socket server correctly with asyncio?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Python 2 has an implemented class with asyncore.dispatcher
I need to implement the same in Python 3.

```
class Server(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, port, socketMap=None):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, None, *socketMap*)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)
    def handle_accept(self):
        sock, addr = self.accept()
        handler = Handler(self, sock, self._map)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            asyncore.loop(0.001, True, self._map, 1)
        self.handle_close()

class Handler(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, server, sock, socketMap):
        self._server = server
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, sock, socketMap)

    def handle_read(self):
        buf = self.recv(8192)
        print(buf)
    def handle_write(self): 

        sent = self.send("hello")
```

I tried to write the following code. But it doesn't work. After the client sends something to the socket, the server does not respond to it, but simply freezes. Please help

```
import socket
import asyncio

class MyAsyncioHandler:

    def __init__(self, reader, writer):
        self.reader = reader
        self.writer = writer

    async def handle_read(self):
        data = await self.reader.read(8192)
        if data:
            print(f"Received data: {data.decode()}")

    async def handle_write(self, data):
        self.writer.write(data)
        await self.writer.drain()

    def handle_close(self):
        print("Connection closed")
        self.writer.close()

async def handle_client(reader, writer):
    handler = MyAsyncioHandler(reader, writer)
    while True:
        await handler.handle_read()
        data_to_send = b"Response data"
        await handler.handle_write(data_to_send)

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_client, '127.0.0.1', 5000    )
    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

To start create a simple asyncio echo server that listens to some address/port you can use following example:

```py
import asyncio


async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)

    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info("peername")

    print(f"Received {message} from {addr}")
    print(f"Send: {message}")

    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Closing the connection")
    writer.close()


async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, "127.0.0.1", 5000)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f"Serving on {addr}")

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Running the code will start the server. In the other terminal you can type this command:

```
$ echo "Hello World" | curl telnet://127.0.0.1:5000
```

The server will respond with `Hello World`

Comment: I've edited the question. COULD YOU HELP ME?

Comment: @test_celery I've posted an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77560087/10035985