# How correct call await func in asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await

I created a socket server with asyncio. Reading from a socket is done immediately, but writing to a socket must be called from another class according to a condition. My implementation doesn't work. Please help
And help pls with stop func. stop() doesn't work
I still don’t understand how to call correctly handle_write()

```
class MyAsyncioHandler:
    def __init__(self, reader, writer):
        self.reader = reader
        self.writer = writer
        self._serverThread = _Thread(self)
        self._serverThread.start()
    async def handle_read(self):
        buf = await self.reader.read(8192)
        print(buf)
    async def handle_write(self, data):
        self.writer.write(data)
        await self.writer.drain()
        self.writer.close()

class NewServer:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.server = None

    async def handle_client(self, reader, writer):
        handler = MyAsyncioHandler(reader, writer)
        await handler.handle_read()
    async def _run(self):
        self.server = await asyncio.start_server(
            self.handle_client, self.host, self.port
        )
        addr = self.server.sockets[0].getsockname()
        log(f"Server: Listen {addr}", INFO)
        async with self.server:
            await self.server.serve_forever()
    def serve(self):
        asyncio.run(self._run())
    def stop(self):
        if self.server:
            self.server.close()
class _Thread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, handler):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._handler = handler
    def run(self):
        if data:
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            loop.create_task(self._handler.handle_write(data))

server = NewServer('localhost', 5000)
server.serve()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
import asyncio


class MyAsyncioHandler:
    def __call__(self, reader, writer):
        async def _inner():
            await self.handle_read(reader)
            data_to_send = b"Response data"
            await self.handle_write(writer, data_to_send)

        return _inner()

    async def handle_read(self, reader):
        data = await reader.read(8192)
        if data:
            print(f"Received data: {data.decode()}")

    async def handle_write(self, writer, data):
        print("Write", data)
        writer.write(data)
        await writer.drain()
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()


async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(MyAsyncioHandler(), "127.0.0.1", 5000)
    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f"Serving on {addr}")
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Running this script will start server on `127.0.0.1:5000`.

On other terminal you can send data to server using this command:

```
$ echo "Hello World" | curl telnet://127.0.0.1:5000
```

Comment: How can I call a function handle_write() from func _Thread.run() correctly?

Comment: the data to be sent is generated in _Thread.run(), so it is from this function that I need to call writing to the socket

Comment: may be  you also now how correct stop server?